# Causing VS2010 debugger to break when Debug.Assert fails

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to cause Visual Studio 2010 to break while debugging when the argument of `Debug.Assert` evaluates to `false`?

Example: in my code I have lines like this:

```
Debug.Assert(!double.IsInfinity(x));
```

If I am not debugging, a window pops up when the assertion fails.

But when I am debugging, the assertion is logged to the "Output" pane, which is easy to miss; there is not popup window and the debugger does not stop. Therefore: is there any way to force the Visual Studio debugger to break when `Debug.Assert` fails?

(BTW: I am developing a WPF based desktop application. In a Windows Forms application, the behavior seems to be differnt: here, the debugger stops on `Debug.Assert`.)

**EDIT**: Please let me clarify: I am **not** looking for an alternative to Debug.Assert(), because my code and external code I use is full of Debug.Assert() statements. I am looking for a way to cause the Visual Studio debugger to break when `Debugg.Assert` fails. (I think earlier VS versions did that, and that the behavior changed in VS2010).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by debugging you mean using "Step Into" feature, see this MS's answer to the problem.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522995/system-diagnostics-debug-assert-doesnt-pop-up-messagebox-correctly-when-step-into-it-in-vs-2010-and-2008

Using "Step Over" at the Assert statement does solve the issue too (for me).

Comment: No, I am referring to the situation when you start a program using the debugger and let it execute (until something bad happens).

Comment: Well, that scenario works for me, using VS 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel and .NET 4

Comment: The Connect article you are mentioned led me on the right track. The problem that I was experiencing is described here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687333/debug-assert-cannot-popup-a-dialog-in-visual-studio-in-the-wpf-project#details . It is a VS2010 bug; as a workaround, it is recommended to switch on the option "Just my code".

Comment: @fmunkert This seems to be broken again in VS2012: "Just my code" is on, but debugger doesn't break on DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use condition breakpoint for this sort of behavior, just set a breakpoint on a line on which you want to break and then right click on the point at the left and choose condition, in popup enter desired condition (in your case is double.IsInfinity(x))

Comment: Please see my clarification above.

Comment: +1 for an interesting fact, although my Debug.Assert calls do not work either and I'd rather fix that then have a load of conditional breakpoints throughout the project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) method (in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace). This will break execution if you are running in a debugger.

Comment: Please see my clarification above.

Comment: ...and crash the application if it runs with no debugger attached!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work as expected for me in a console application at least: in debug builds, a dialog pops up that allows you to break into the application using the debugger, but in release builds, nothing happens. Admittedly, I just used a simplistic `Debug.Assert(false);`, but I don't see why that should make much of a difference. I'm running Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate.

I'd suggest that you take a close look at your build settings.

Here's the code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written a small WPF project that contains only a button which executes the line `Debug.Assert(false)`. If I start this program with the debugger, the debugger will not stop and no popup dialog is displayed. I am using VS2010 Premium with SP1; are you using a different version?

Comment: That's odd. I'm using VS2010 Ultimate + SP1, and did my test in a console application. (Answer updated to indicate this.) Maybe that is worth trying, to scale away as many layers as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just throw an exception when `!double.IsInfinity(x)` instead of using an assertion?

Comment: I do not think that exceptions are the right way to check for logic errors during program development.

Comment: fmunkert - I thought that the condition you specified represented a excptional value for x. If it's not, then it probably not the way to go. What about just setting a conditional breakpoint there? That will only break when the value false. Also, setting the condition to `double.IsInfinity(x)`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your app removed the default TraceListener from the Debug class, and replaced it with a custom one that implements the `Fail(string)` method differently.

You may be able to track it down by searching your code for `Debug.Listeners` and see if somewhere the default one is cleared out or modified, or see if you've got a `trace` section in your app.config.

By default, from what I've read, you should definitely get the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

If using the `DefaultTraceListener` you can add the following section to your `app.config` file which enables breaking on `Debug.Assert(false)`:

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <assert assertuienabled="false"/>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

For details see [`assert` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty5e4c4h(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DefaultTraceListener.AssertUiEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.assertuienabled(v=vs.110).aspx).