# Debug.Assert does not break into editor in MonoDevelop/MonoTouch

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, monodevelop, assert

Simply put, `Debug.Assert` calls that fail don't stop the execution flow of the program in MonoDevelop, they just print out a trace message that starts like this (followed by a stack trace):

```
2012-12-28 19:21:01.978 TestApp[81689:c07] ---- DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED ----
2012-12-28 19:21:01.979 TestApp[81689:c07] ---- Assert Short Message ----
```

What can I do to force the failed `Debug.Asserts` to break execution at the `Assert` in MonoDevelop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Causing VS2010 debugger to break when Debug.Assert fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633265/causing-vs2010-debugger-to-break-when-debug-assert-fails)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that post, this one is about MonoDevelop, not Visual Studio.

Comment: After a bit more research, it seems like I would need to write a custom TraceListener that then calls Debugger.Break manually, but I would expect such default behavior to be available in Mono or MonoDevelop...

Comment: I retagged it from monotouch to mono because this is a general mono problem and not specific to monotouch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debugger integration parts of `Debug.Assert` are not implemented yet - see [Xamarin bug #4650](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4650).

I already had a quick look at this a couple of months ago, then realized that doing it right would probably require runtime support to auto-unwind the top frames (so MonoDevelop would stop on the `Debug.Assert` statement, not somewhere in the trace listener implementation).

As a workaround, you can add a custom trace listener and call `Debugger.Break()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Martin. For what it's worth, even a break without an auto-unwind would be more useful than the current situation right now (especially if it was a simple flag to toggle this behavior). Will look into custom trace listeners as suggested.

Comment: So, calling Debugger.Break() in _MonoTouch_ (running iOS code in simulator) simply kills execution of the running app. Any thoughts?