# Why is DefaultTraceListener.AssertUiEnabled sometimes false when debugging and using QuickWatch

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2013, tracelistener

I'm debugging a small WPF application with VS2013 Community, .Net 4.5, and a 3rd party graphing library, and sometimes when I F5-Launch, my Debug.Assert failures don't prompt or break in the debugger, they only get written to the debug output... (expected behavior if AssertUiEnabled == false, but... I'm leaving it true).

I'm using the DefaultTraceListener, and I have not defined an <assert> element in my configuration file.

I can't reproduce reliably, but I've witnessed while debugging that sometimes `((DefaultTraceListener)Debug.Listeners[0]).AssertUiEnabled` == false, and it seems to happen when I start using QuickWatch and/or F10 stepping through code. My perception is that it's related to switching the active window away from the wpf app that's being debugged. AssertUiEnabled starts true, and then after *unknown repro steps that include F10-StepOver and CtrlDQ-QuickWatch* I observe it to be false.

**QUESTION: Is there any reason for AssertUiEnabled to be setting itself to false when I'm switching between windows or opening/closing the QuickWatch window in VS2013?**

I believe what I'm seeing is root cause for [Causing VS2010 debugger to break when Debug.Assert fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633265/causing-vs2010-debugger-to-break-when-debug-assert-fails) - (OP asking why he's not getting debugger to break on assert.fail)

I've read some articles about adding [custom TraceListeners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5699/Automatically-break-into-code-when-calling-Debug-A) when debugging web services, and how the [DefaultTraceListener in Mono defaults to AssertUiEnabled = false](http://do-the-right-things.blogspot.com/2014/05/clr-and-mono-runtime-difference_13.html) but I think the .Net 4.5 runtime's DefaultTraceListener is what I want, it's just self-disabling the AssertUI for unknown reason. I can work around it but I'm curious why the value is changing.