# Debug.Assert not always working in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, assert

I have a strange problem with Asserts being ignored. You can reproduce it with this minimal example. I am wondering why this problem occurs and how to face it:

```
public class TestAssert
{
    public string EmptyString
    {
        get
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void ShowAssertIgnored()
    {
        var foo = dict[EmptyString];
    }
}
```

You can see that the `Debug.Assert(false)` is ignored even though the property is evaluated. Just call

```
var test = new TestAssert();
test.ShowAssertIgnored();
```

and you should see what I mean (also shown on the image).[image: Debug.Assert is not evaluated but the property is]

The code is ***compiled and run in Debug*** (other asserts work fine!), 32 bit, x86 + AnyCPU, VS2012 professional, .Net Framework 4

**Edit:**
The project is a console application and I was running it for several times in a row. Having a breakpoint before `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);` most often a messagebox appears. But not always: When I just retry the same situation several times I sometimes see the result in the console.

To say it again: I can reproduce non-deterministic behaviour in the VS2012 debugger!

Comment: Does step-by-step debugging pass through the `Debug.Assert` line? Have you tried putting a breakpoint there?

Comment: Try to recreate the issue in a new project.  I just tried with a simple console app and it hit the assert.  Therefore, there's nothing specifically wrong with your code *as presented in the question*.   There must be some other issue in your environment/vs setup

Comment: What's the project type of the calling code?  What's the project type of the code that this is in?  console app / winforms / class?  Where are the 'other asserts' that work defined?   What if you add one in `ShowAssertIgnored()`?

Comment: did a coworked, as a joke, add `#undef DEBUG` in your file ?

Comment: There is no `#undef DEBUG` and other Asserts work. But as you can see int the edit I have different results for different runs.

Comment: I have solved my problem by throwing an Exception since the error condition I am checking is not only for developing. For curiosity I am still interested what may be the reason for this strange behaviour.

Comment: Other than compiler optimizations, or a lack of a message loop (or a default listener which may throw), it makes no sense. I copied the code on a new project and it works perfectly. Something on your project is not right, but it's nothing that you have shown in your question.

Comment: Enabling "Just My Code" in Debug options could solve the issue. see comments of the accepted solution of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7633351/2629311

Answer (score 8):

If you read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll see that `Debug.Assert` isn't designed to throw.

> Typically, the Assert(Boolean) method is used to identify logic errors during program development. Assert evaluates the condition. If the result is false, it sends a failure message to the Listeners collection. You can customize this behavior by adding a TraceListener to, or removing one from, the Listeners collection.
>
> When the application runs in user interface mode, it displays a message box that shows the call stack with file and line numbers. The message box contains three buttons: Abort, Retry, and Ignore. Clicking the Abort button terminates the application. Clicking Retry sends you to the code in the debugger if your application is running in a debugger, or offers to open a debugger if it is not. Clicking Ignore continues with the next instruction in the code.

If running in an UI environment, it may trigger throw-like behaviour that is defined in the listeners that the UI environment/test-runner sets up.

So, in short, `Debug.Assert(false)` won't halt your application but its listeners might.

Assuming that there is no UI here... If you want your code to fail, then you'll need to write your own TraceListener:

```
public class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string msg)
    {
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string msg)
    {
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
}
```

and add it to the listeners collection:

```
Debug.Listeners.Add(new MyTraceListener());
```

Comment: I am running a Program with UI and expect the messagebox to appear. However, NOT ALWAYS this messagebox appears. Sometimes it just prints to the console. However, I am running the same settings without any change.

Comment: Why do you assume that throw behavior is desiderd? The issue is that Debug.Assert is ignored, not that it does not throw exceptions. In fact, this is a recurrent bug in Visual Studio (2010 for me): after some undefined time (or after an undefined event occurs), Debug.Assert stop working. Sometimes a VS restart is required to get them working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your project settings to define the DEBUG constant? The Debug.Assert() methods have the [ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")] attribute, which means, they will by ignored during compilation, if the "DEBUG" constant is not defined.

Comment: As stated by freedomn-m the code is compiled and run as Debug

Comment: the build configuration named "Debug" does not necessarily define the  DEBUG constant!

Comment: At some point the problem disappeared. However, I am not aware of the change I did. Maybe this idea is correct and I didn't have the DEBUG constant defined. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Just hit this with Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.7) with some .NET 5.0 C# projects which have had "Define DEBUG constant" checked for years in their project properties without `<DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>` in their .csproj files. Something caused the setting become unchecked and manually rechecking it inserted `<DefineConstants>` in the projects. Since the VS installation and solution nugets were stable I've no plausible explanation for why this might occur.

Answer (score 0):

That's an *expected behaviour*, `Debug.Assert()` works in *debug build only*:

> By default, the Debug.Assert method works only in debug builds. Use
>   the Trace.Assert method if you want to do assertions in release
>   builds. For more information, see Assertions in Managed Code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z(v=vs.110).aspx

use `Trace.Assert()` if you want it working in release as well.

Comment: *"The code is compiled and run in Debug"* quote from OP

Comment: As stated by freedomn-m the code is compiled and run as Debug